# Dashboard URL filter not working

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I am trying to use the Spring'21 salesforce feature that is to filter the dashboard with URL parameters. I am using the below 2 links as a reference[image]:

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_rd_dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5&release=230

Normal Dashboard

**To this I have added a filter with ?fv0=myAccountName, but the filter is not changing. Kindly provide appropriate solution or if anything is not correct**

[image]

**this is the error message if I use &fv0=myAccountName**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the following to the end of your dashboard URL

`&fv0=youraccount` which will look like this `?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=youraccount`

There's no need for a `?` again before your filter as you already have parameters (and a `?`) in your URL for `queryScope` and simply just need to add a new parameter with `&` as the documentation mentions

> To add filters to the URL, use this structure:
>
> &—Denotes a new parameter in the URL. If no other parameters are
> present in the URL, then substitute ? in place of &.

Likewise, **the value you pass into the URL must exist in the filter dropdown** for it to work - otherwise, it displays a `this filter URL is invalid`.

Comment: okay, then it's showing "The filter URL is invalid, please try again"

Comment: are you typing this in to the URL bar or how are you testing this? A screenshot in your question would be helpful

Comment: This is my url ending with: /view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=hema

Comment: Now, I have added the screenshot to my question. Kindly check

Comment: Did you check that whatever account name you're passing in the filter actually exists in the dropdown for Account Name in the dashboard filter? I only get that error if the value does not exist in the filter.

Comment: So you are telling I cannot pass any name; it should match with any of the existing filter value.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to overcome a salesforce limitation that is up to 50 filter values. I thought this can be achieved using URL by passing any value. Is there any other way to extend or avoid this limit

Comment: I don't think so. They have a [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336682&type=1&mode=1) saying there's no further increases and this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DzE1AAK) hasn't gained much traction.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the filter value you are passing HAS to be a pre-defined selectable value in the dashboard filter(s).

You can not pass in anything you please.

I have created a reasonable solution (there are scaling limits) to this issue if you want to check it out on my blog here https://salesforceconfig.com/show-any-accounts-data-on-a-universal-dashboard/